# Generating key-value to JToken

Tags: c#, json, key-value

I have key-value JToken, which server sends to me. How I can do the same via json.net?

Example:

```
{
  "1_type": "sound",
  "1url": "http://example.com/sound.mp3",
  "2_type": "url",
  "2url": "http://example.com",
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
JObject jObj = new JObject();
jObj["1_type"] = "sound";
jObj["1url"] = "http://example.com/sound.mp3";
jObj["2_type"] = "url";
jObj["2url"] = "http://example.com";
var jsonString = jObj.ToString();
```